# Как в PyQt открыть .html файл?

Tags: python, html, pyqt, qwebengineview, qurl

Можно ли в *PyQt4* открыть **.html** файл?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь http://agateau.com/2012/pyqtwebkit-experiments-part-2-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

Вот как это может выглядеть в PyQt5:

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self ):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Пример загрузки и отображения локальной страницы')

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()  

        # Загрузка локальной страницы
        # Полный путь к index.html
        url = 'E:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5/SHABLONS/PyQt5-master/Chapter05/index.html'
        self.browser.load(QUrl( url ))  
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)       
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello PyQt5</h1>
    <h2>Hello PyQt5</h2>
    <h3>hello PyQt5</h3>
    <h4>hello PyQt5</h4>
    <h5>hello PyQt5</h5>
    <h6>Hello PyQt5</h6>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в PyQt4 никак нельзя?

Comment: Нет ничего невозможного, но я Вам советую перейти на PyQt5

Comment: Можете показать пример на PyQt4?